# Is there a PHP refactoring tool to tell what functions are never called?

Tags: php, refactoring

I have a large codebase which has suffered many changes over the years. I would like to remove the functions that are no longer called or relevant. Is there a tool that will analysis the codebase and determine if a method is ever used?

I'm also using phpunit/xdebug which reports which functions have not been run for the unit tests, however coverage is only at 55% and will require a massive amount of work to bring it up to 100% (I'm working on it!).

Anything that was a command line tool would be extra good as I could hook it into hudson (CI).